# How to run lambda function on a schedule in my localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam

I have a task that need to be scheduled on aws lambda function. I wrote a SAM template as below and I see it works when deploying on aws environment (my function get triggered intervally).

But we want to do testing on dev environment first before deploying. I use `sam local start-api [OPTIONS]` to deploy our functions to dev environment. But the problem is that, every functions configured as rest API work, but the schedule task not. I'm not sure is it possible on local/dev environment or not. If not, please suggest a solution (is [it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html) possible?). Thank you

This is template:

```yaml
aRestApi:
    ...
    ...
sendMonthlyReport:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src.monthlyReport
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Events:
        ScheduledEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: "cron(* * * * *)"
```

Comment: AWS Lambda functions run on AWS, not locally. If you have some way to run them locally at dev time, for example SAM or serverless, then combine their CLI with whatever cron/schedule capability your OS offers.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for local testing before deployment of lambda functions you will probably be fed this resource by the quote-unquote "google": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html

However, there are other ways to do it.

I personally use the public docker image from aws.

Here is an example of the docker image created for a specific use case of mine.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN yum -y install tar gzip zlib freetype-devel \
    gcc \
    ghostscript \
    lcms2-devel \
    libffi-devel \
    libimagequant-devel \
    .
    enter code here
    enter code here
    and some more dependencies .... 
    && yum clean all


COPY requirements.txt ./


RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# Replace Pillow with Pillow-SIMD to take advantage of AVX2
RUN pip uninstall -y pillow && CC="cc -mavx2" pip install -U --force-reinstall pillow-simd

COPY <handler>.py ./<handler>.py

# Set the CMD to your handler
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3.8","app5.py" ]
```

In your case, follow instructions for node and run the docker image locally. If it works, you can then continue with aws lambda creation/update.

I see that you also have a cron job, why not use the cron job to invoke this lambda function separately and not define it in you SAML?

There are a number of ways you can invoke a lambda function based on event.
For example to invoke using cli: (For aws-cliv2)

make sure you configure awscli

```
# !/bin/bash
export AWS_PROFILE=<your aws profile>
export AWS_REGION=<aws region>

aws lambda invoke --function-name <function name> \
--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
--log-type Tail \
--payload <your json payload > \
<output filename>
```

Makes it loosely coupled.

Then you can use carlo's node cronjob suggestion to invoke is as many times you like, free of charge.

Comment: Question edited. Could you help to check?

Comment: Did you try following the docker suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I used `localstack` for the demonstrate. LocalStack is a cloud service emulator that runs in a single container on your laptop or in your CI environment. You can see more detail in this link https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: Can you provide extra context or links to the AWS local stack?

Comment: @DrRobLang LocalStack is a cloud service emulator that runs in a single container on your laptop or in your CI environment. You can see more detail in this link [https://github.com/localstack/localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now please edit your answer so that it is easier to find.

Answer (score -1):

I would use node-cron to set a scheduler on a node file to run.

npm install --save node-cron

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
    console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

You can also check for this [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples) tutorial!

Comment: This is not a AWS specific answer, it's a nodejs answer

Comment: Hi @chrishollinworth! The user meant to ask how to set a scheduler locally. That's why he accepted.